# Piston customize response representation

Tags: python, django, rest, django-piston

I am using piston and I would like to spit out a custom format for my response.

My model is something like this:

```
class Car(db.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   color = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Now when I issue a GET request to something like /api/cars/1/ I want to get a response like this:

```
{'name' : 'BMW', 'color' : 'Blue',
  'link' : {'self' : '/api/cars/1'}
}
```

However piston only outputs this:

```
{'name' : 'BMW', 'color' : 'Blue'}
```

In other words I want to customize the representation of a particular resource.

My piston Resource handler currently looks like this:

```
class CarHandler(AnonymousBaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)
    model = Car
    fields = ('name', 'color',)

    def read(self, request, car_id):
           return Car.get(pk=car_id)
```

So I don't really get where I have the chance to customize the data. Unless I have to overwrite the JSON emitter, but that seems like a stretch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return custom format by returning a Python dictionary. Here is an example on one of my app. I hope it helps.

```
from models import *
from piston.handler import BaseHandler
from django.http import Http404

class ZipCodeHandler(BaseHandler):
    methods_allowed = ('GET',)

    def read(self, request, zip_code):
        try:
            points = DeliveryPoint.objects.filter(zip_code=zip_code).order_by("name")
            dps = []
            for p in points:
                name = p.name if (len(p.name)<=16) else p.name[:16]+"..."
                dps.append({'name': name, 'zone': p.zone, 'price': p.price})
            return {'length':len(dps), 'dps':dps}    
        except Exception, e:
            return {'length':0, "error":e}
```

Comment: So you CAN return a dictionary! Great stuff, didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this is a pleasant surprise!

Answer (score 1):

Its been two years since this question was asked, so its obviously late for OP. But for others who, like me, had a similar dilemma there exists a **Pistonic** way to get this done.

Using the Django example of polls and choices -

You will notice that for the ChoiceHandler the JSON response is:

```
[
    {
        "votes": 0,
        "poll": {
            "pub_date": "2011-04-23",
            "question": "Do you like Icecream?",
            "polling_ended": false
        },
        "choice": "A lot!"
    }
]
```

This includes the entire JSON for the associated poll whereas just the `id` for it could have been just as good if not better.

Let's say that the **desired** response is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "votes": 0,
        "poll": 5,
        "choice": "A lot!"
    }
]
```

Here's how you would edit the handler to achieve that:

```
from piston.handler import BaseHandler
from polls.models import Poll, Choice

class ChoiceHandler( BaseHandler ):
  allowed_methods = ('GET',)
  model = Choice
  # edit the values in fields to change what is in the response JSON
  fields = ('id', 'votes', 'poll', 'choice') # Add id to response fields
  # if you do not add 'id' here, the desired response will not contain it 
  # even if you have defined the classmethod 'id' below

  # customize the response JSON for the poll field to be the id 
  # instead of the complete JSON for the poll object
  @classmethod
  def poll(cls, model):
    if model.poll:
      return model.poll.id
    else:
      return None

  # define what id is in the response
  # this is just for descriptive purposes, 
  # Piston has built-in id support which is used when you add it to 'fields'
  @classmethod
  def id(cls, model):
    return model.id

  def read( self, request, id=None ):
    if id:
      try:
        return Choice.objects.get(id=id)
      except Choice.DoesNotExist, e:
        return {}
    else:
      return Choice.objects.all()
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for a nested field? Seems like piston only supports unnested, based on its emitters.py

Answer (score -2):

Django comes with a serialization library. You'll also need a json library to get it into the format you want

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

```
from django.core import serializers
import simplejson

class CarHandler(AnonymousBaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)
    model = Car
    fields = ('name', 'color',)

    def read(self, request, car_id):
           return simplejson.dumps( serializers.serialize("json", Car.get(pk=car_id) )
```

Comment: The question is about how to add fields to object JSON representation, not how to produce JSON.